# How much health do MOAB class bloons have?

Tags: bloons-td-5, bloons-monkey-city, bloons-td-battles

How much health do MOAB class bloons have? I was wondering and I noticed the that MOAB Assassin can destroy 1 MOAB, and 1000 dmg to ZOMGs. Does that mean MOABs have 1000 health? How about BFBs and ZOMGS?

Comment: The Bloons wiki has the RBEs for each MOAB bloon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MOAB RBE (Red Bloon Equivalent) is 616.

BFB RBE is 3164.

ZOMG RBE is 16656.

Sometimes it differs from game to game but these are the excepted numbers because it applies to the most amount of versions of the game.

You can read the rest of the information here:
http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Bloon_Types

Comment: @sensiwoo You're welcome :)

Comment: Above answer includes Child spawns (i.e ZOMG into 4 BFBs, etc). MOAB only is 200, BFB only is 600, ZOMG only is 4000 (revival of old post)